# How to remove space between a symbol and the text in an itemize section in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, itemize, context-mkiv

## MWE

Consider this:

```
language=uk
\setupbodyfont[libertine,12pt]
\setupitemgroup[textdistance=none,leftmargin=standard]

\starttext

\title{My Points}

Here are the points:
\startitemize
    \item point 1,
    \item point 2
    \item and point 3.
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

It should compile with the latest version of ConTeXt.

## Problem

The example above generates a (text) list with bullet points (symbol). The distance between the text and the symbol is too big for my liking:

[image]

How can I reduce it?

## Things I tried

Of course I tried the `serried` option and the `textdistance` option in order to remove the unwanted space, to no avail. By the way, `textdistance` does not seem to do anything whatsoever.

## Refs

http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupitemgroup

## Version

```
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 0.63
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2016.05.17 19:20
```

Comment: Are you sure that you've got the syntax right? According to [web resources](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupitemgroup) `\setupitemgroup` has four arguments. As an example, the declaration `\setupitemgroup[itemize][1][serried][distance=0em]` has an effect on the list.

Comment: This is quite new to me, but from what I understood, these arguments are always optional. In practice `leftmargin=standard` works for instance. By not declaring any other thing, it applies to everything `\setupitemgroup` can handle, so I don't have to repeat that for `enumerates` and the likes. However that might be completely wrong.

Comment: By the way, what you are suggesting does not work either here... I guess this is, once again, a bug.

Comment: I'm no expert for ConTeXt, but I guess you need at least empty brackets as arguments, `[]`. How else can ConTeXt know that you argument is meant to be the fourth one?

Comment: It expects different types of input. More particularly, ConTeXt cannot mix keyword arguments with raw arguments. Anyway, your suggestion unfortunately does not work in my setup (TeXLive 2016 with the given ConTeXt version): the distance just does not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To control the indentation from the left margin, use the `leftmargin` parameter.  The distance to the symbol is a little trickier.   The symbol is put in a hbox of a certain width controlled with `width`.  Between this box and the item text there is a certain distance controlled by `distance`.  The defaults for the above parameters are (from [`strc-itm.mkvi`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/base/mkiv/strc-itm.mkvi#L1740))

```
rightmargin=0pt
width=1.5em
distance=0pt
```

As `distance` is already `0pt` we could either set this to a negative value or just reduce `width`.  I went for reducing `width`.   You have been using `\setupitemgroup` to set the parameters.  However, your setup did not work because you forgot the *name* of the item group.  It should have been `\setupitemgroup[itemize]`.  You might come across `\setupitemize` which is just a shorthand for `\setupitemgroup[itemize]` but should be avoided because it [is obsolete](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/base/mkiv/strc-itm.mkvi#L333) and might be removed in the future.

```
\setupitemgroup
  [itemize]
  [
    leftmargin=1em,
    width=1em,
  ]

\starttext

\starttitle[title={My Points}]

  Here are the points:
  \startitemize
  \item point 1,
  \item point 2
  \item and point 3.
  \stopitemize

\stoptitle

\stoptext
```

[image]

---

Addendum:  `textdistance` has an effect.  It's just not the effect you were looking for.

```
\starttext

\setupitemgroup
  [itemize]
  [textdistance=small]
\startitemize[text]
\item point 1
\item point 2
\stopitemize

\setupitemgroup
  [itemize]
  [textdistance=big]
\startitemize[text]
\item point 1
\item point 2
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you just picked the wrong parameters. The following code affects the distances roughly as you want. `margin` controls the distance between left border and item symbol, and `distance` the distance between item symbol and item text.

```
\setupbodyfont[libertine,12pt]
\setupitemize[margin=0.5em,distance=-0.5em]
\starttext
\title{My Points}
Here are the points:
\startitemize
    \item point 1,
    \item point 2
    \item and point 3.
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: It is true that the options `margin` and `leftmargin` are synonyms.  However, it would be more clear which margin is adjusted if you used `leftmargin`.

Comment: I prefer tackling the root of the problem (here `width`) rather than adding a negative offset. Though you spent time working on something which is working, so I am upvoting this.